Apache Nifi - Local changes after reboot node
After the restart of one of the nodes of Nifi, local changes are displayed that were never made, this problem was reflected since we made the upgrade from version 1.11.4 to version 1.22.0.
I understand that the problem is with the flow.xml.gz file but I do not know what would be the cause of it, does anyone know or did something similar happen?
Nifi version 1.22.0
Registry 1.17.0
We tested to eliminate the flow.xml.gz file so that it generates it once the node is turned on and also we tested that all have the same flow.xml.gz.
On the other hand we also tried to import again the flow from the registry, but at the moment of restarting it shows again non-existent local changes.
From the logs of nifi-app.log we could only visualize that we found differences in the flow
“there are 382 differences to take into account”.
